# AJAX, добавление данных в бд и их вывод

Tags: php, ajax

Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться с этим вопросом.

Форма (насколько я понимаю, роль submit-а исполняет ajax запрос):

```
<form action="html_post.php" method="post">

            <textarea id="textarea" name="posting"> </textarea>

            <input onclick="add_post()" class="button" type="button" name="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

И запрос:

```
function add_post() {
         $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: "add_post.php",
               data: {
                      content: $('#textarea').val()
                    }
               });
            }
```

Вот этим скриптом посты должны были бы добавляться в бд:

```
session_start();

  $name = $_SESSION['name']; 
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];

  if ((isset($_POST['send']))) {
    if (strlen($_POST['posting']) >= 5) {
        $post = htmlspecialchars($_POST['posting']);
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $update = "INSERT INTO post(content, user_id, checked, date) VALUES('$post', '$id', 'true', '$date')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    echo json_encode(array('ok' => 'AJAX OK!!!'));
 }
}
```

Дамп таблицы:

```
 INSERT INTO post (post_id, user_id, content, checked, date) 
 VALUES (173, 15, ' first_post', 'false', '2017-12-25 02:01:24'), 
 (171, 15, ' second', 'false', '2017-12-25 02:00:56'), 
 (172, 15, ' why_it_does_not_work :c', 'false', '2017-12-25 02:01:13')
```

В логах нет ответа, и в базу ничего не добавляется, но запрос идет.

У меня еще нет полного понимания Ajax-а, поэтому буду неимоверно благодарна тем, кто подскажет как правильно написать этот код и/или объяснит, где здесь ошибка.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70760/discussion-on-question-by--ajax-------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простое взаимодействие с **БД** через драйвер **mysqli** [[источник]](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php):

```
// подключение к БД
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
// проверка соединения
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
// выполнение запроса с присвоением его результата переменной для дальнейшей обработки
if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO post(content, user_id, checked, date) VALUES('$post', '$id', 'true', '$date')") === TRUE) {
    echo "Запись добавлена.\n";
}
// закрытие соединения
$mysqli->close();
```

Такая форма записи позволяет контролировать выполнение подключения к БД, выполнение запроса и возвращаемые данные.

Простой **jQuery.AJAX** запрос:

```
data = $("форма").serialize(); 
// наиболее простой и рабочий способ передавать данные форм ajax-запросом
// serialize() превращает объект формы в строчку вида query_string
// вида query_string (параметры get-запроса &name=value).
// name - атрибут name элемента формы, value - значение 

$.ajax({
    type : "post" // "get"
    url  : url,
    data : data,
    success : function(data){

        console.info(data); // выведем в консоль ответ обработчика
        // если файл(функция/класс/метод)-обработчик возвращает что-либо
        // (echo/return/print etc.), это вернётся объектом data здесь. 
        // В вашем случае это строка в формате json
    },
    error: function(xhr){

        console.error("Всё плохо: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        // в случае неудачного ajax-запроса объект xhr вернётся сюда со 
        // статусом запроса (ошибкой) 
    }

});
```

Такая форма записи позволяет контролировать выполнение **AJAX**.

Ваш обработчик должен выглядеть минимально так:

```
session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['name']; 
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO post(content, user_id, checked, date) VALUES('$post', '$id', 'true', '$date')") === TRUE) {
    echo "Запись добавлена.\n";
}

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['posting']) >= 5) {
        $post = htmlspecialchars($_POST['posting']);
        // тут у вас была ошибка, т.к. вы присваивали $post значение $_POST['posting']
        // но передавали в обработчик $_POST['content']
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $update = "INSERT INTO post(content, user_id, checked, date) VALUES('$post', '$id', 'true', '$date')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $update);
        echo json_encode(array('ok' => 'AJAX OK!!!'));
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка: Длина строки меньше 5ти символов.";
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: insert_id полагаю. Это зависит от нужд логики.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {
   content: $('#textarea').val()
}
```

В этой части кода, вы по сути определяете ключ глобальной переменной `$_POST`. Поэтому на стороне сервера, принимайте с этим учетом - `$_POST['content']`, а не `$_POST['posting']`. Однако, вас это не устроит, т.к. кроме значения `textarea`, как я могу видеть из вашего кода, вам нужно передавать и другие данные формы. В таком случае, можно использовать метод [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "add_post.php",
    data: $('form_selector').serialize()
});
```

Где **form_selector** - селектор вашей формы. Кроме того, нужно предотвращать выполнение события `submit`, а иначе данные формы будут передаваться обычным способом: `event.preventDefault()` или `return false`

Comment: ухты, удобный этот метод, serialize(). Сейчас попробую. С формы передаются только 2 значения: сам текст и значение checkbox-а, который определяет глобальные пост или нет. Но это уже другая история. И у меня ведь нету submit

Comment: В каком смысле нету submit? А зачем тогда button?

Comment: @stckvrw, говорю же: из того, что я поняла во время изучения ajax, эта кнопка исполняет роль submit. Т.е. все данные передаются ajax-ом

Comment: @Біпач, на тип кнопки я не обратил внимания, но хотел бы сказать о другом, т.к. далеко не являюсь поклонником установки обработчиков событий inline. Если функция `add_post` у вас предназначена только для этой формы, то гораздо логичней было бы для кнопки всё-таки установить тип `submit` и записать так: `$('form_selector').on('submit', function(e){  e.preventDefault(); /* дальше код передачи данных ajax-ом */ });`. Только не забудьте убрать `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаком с `mysqli_` но если не важно какой драйвер тогда попробуйте такой код для **add_post.php**:

```
if($_POST['posting'] && strlen($_POST['posting']) >= 5) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8','username','password');
    $user_id = 15;
    $post = htmlspecialchars($_POST['posting']);
    $checked = 'false';
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO post (user_id, content, checked, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($user_id, $post, $checked, $date));
}
```

Не забудьте вписать в строке `$pdo = new PDO(...)` название своей базы, а также логин и пароль к ней

Если запустить данный файл, то он успешно добавляет данные в таблицу, проверил. Поэтому если у вас не заработает, значит проблема в чем то другом

Comment: Спасибо, но я еще не выучила ООП и, собственно, pdo

Comment: @Біпач вместо хранения инфо в базе данных можете подумать о flat-file т.е хранении данных в файлах, сейчас это считается более прогрессивная технология, на которую уже переходят некоторые программисты

Comment: @stcvrw, спасибо, учту) но сначала основы выучу